# Unit test failing on two equal Qstrings (one is read from a file)?

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qt4

I'm trying to compare two string which are supposed to be the same. The test however fails.

I'm testing if the file get set correctly by the `router.setForwarding(true)` method.

Here is the code of the test.

```
void router_test::testSetForwarding_true()
{
    QFile myfile("/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward");
    myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text);        
    router->setForwarding(true);   
    QString forward = QString(myfile.readAll());

    QCOMPARE(QString("1"),forward);
}
```

As a result I get:

```
   FAIL!  : router_test::testSetForwarding_true() Compared values are not the same
   Actual (QString("1")): 1
   Expected (forward): 1
```

Why aren't they equal?

Comment: Sure there is not a \n at the end of your ip_forward file?

Comment: use `forward.trimmed()`. BTW: `QCOMPARE` arguments should have reversed order :) (logs would have a proper description).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can glean from the output, you have interchanged the actual and expected values. You're also comparing the newline-terminated output against one without a newline.

This should work:

```
QCOMPARE(forward, QString("1\n"));
```

or

```
QCOMPARE(forward[0], QChar('1'));
```